# Can Flutterflow app access MySQL database from my Google Cloud Instance?

Tags: mysql, flutter

I will create a mobile app for Android and iOS. The purpose of the app is to access just a segment of the MySQL database, that part is for customers (the rest of the database is used by employees via my web application).
Is there a way the for FlutterFlow app to access MySQL database instead of FireBase Storage? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Though flutterflow has default integration with Firebase firestore database,
below 2 approaches can be used.

1. API integration approach can be used to use MYSQL database.

Please refer below flow:

- You can have backend Server which will host the API.
- This backend server will have integration with MYSQL DB
- API's will be consumed in flutterflow app

  https://docs.flutterflow.io/data-and-backend/api-calls

2. Custom code approach (Though have not used it before)

https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/manage-custom-code-in-github

Comment: There is a custom code option in FlutterFlow. Can I use that instead of building API just for 2 GET requests? I wish to pull data directly from the database. 

https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/custom-functions

Comment: Yes U can use that too